# 2d mathematics equation grapher for Windows

Tags: windows, graphs, math

Is there a simple, free equation grapher for Windows? I would like this program to include Cartesian coordinates and polar coordinates. I am running 64-bit Windows 7.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [GeoGebra](http://www.geogebra.org/cms/en/):

- Free (+ [portable version available](http://www.geogebra.org/cms/en/portable))
- Since GeoGebra 4 [it's possible to change the grid type to polar](http://www.geogebra.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=21462)
- Works with Windows/Mac/Linux (even Android/iPhone/Windows Phone as well as in Google Chrome)

[image]

Comment: The GeoGebra team also published an app for Windows 8 some weeks or months ago. (However, it does not support all features yet.)